# Google Static Maps Polyline Issue

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-static-api

I am attempting to create a Google Static Map with a Path drawn on it. I am receiving a Static Map back, but the map is zoomed really far out and the poly line is cutting clear through continents and oceans.

**Am I building the Google Static Maps API URL Properly?** If I am not, what can I do to change it. The polyLine List is retrieved by using a Direction API call.

**Separating the List polyLines and creating the Path portion of the URL**

```
if (polyLines != null && polyLines.size() > 0) {
    url.append("&path=" + URLEncoder.encode("weight:10|color:blue|enc:", "UTF-8"));
    for (String polyline : polyLines) {
        url.append(URLEncoder.encode(polyline, "UTF-8"));
    }
}
```

**HERE IS THE FINAL URL**

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=1080x1080&scale=2&format=png&markers=icon%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fdial7.limosys.com%3A7771%2FJlimoWSJson%2Ficons%2Fpu_marker_64.png%7C40.8830388%2C-73.9498278&markers=%7Cicon%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fdial7.limosys.com%3A7771%2FJlimoWSJson%2Ficons%2Fdo_marker_64.png%7C40.8362248602332%2C-73.94620008246969&path=weight%3A10%7Ccolor%3Ablue%7Cenc%3A%7D%7DoxFhijbMb%40l%40r%40p%40r%40h%40f%40V%5ERz%40XdFjAgnoxFdrjbMj%40iAXk%40%5Eu%40Vm%40Vm%40LWDKPc%40khoxFtgjbM%7C%40h%40LHJDZPd%40PPFjA%5EdB%60%40xCf%40%7CCl%40nF%7E%40fAXbAVx%40ZhAd%40NFNFf%40VnAp%40lAv%40nCzBbAp%40t%40d%40n%40b%40JDb%40Xt%40%5E%7E%40%60%40p%40Td%40LZFPB%5EF%60ALxATlALp%40FT%40VB%5EBV%3FrBDP%40V%40VBP%40NBND%5CHRFTFTLNHRJPNNJXV%5E%5CTTZZ%60%40XNJVNb%40V%5CPb%40TZNRJl%40ZXR%5ER%5CVXX%5Eb%40lAtAnAxANPDFx%40%7E%40axkxF%60albMJPHMBG%40A%40A%40A%40%3FB%3FB%3FB%3FB%40ZNRZXd%40X%5Cf%40t%40tArAnA%7E%40JFD%40LHJDB%40FDv%40%60%40p%40ThJvC%7CBhAdCxAr%40%5CbAj%40nBr%40tA%5EXHB%3FXH%40%40F%3FZJB%40%40%3FB%40B%40H%40%40%40%40%3F%40%3F%40%40D%40%40%3F%40%40D%40JB%40%3F%40%3FHB%40%3FLDj%40LDBHDHHDDFHFLBJ%40HBL%3FJ%3FD%3FD%3FLABAHCLCLGLOPMHGBQBM%3FQCIEGGIEEGCGGIEQEMAO%3FO%3FQBO%40Q%40KBUDSDYDa%40%40Y%3FCCq%40%5CuCd%40gE%7CCoXv%40uG%7E%40cIRyAlBiPbAyIv%40yGv%40mHPkBD_%40PoB%40%3FViCioixFreibMVe%40%40C%3FABKBMBSHs%40DY%3FC%40A%3FEHo%40Jy%40%40CBQ%40M%40M%3FABSF%5BF%5DPc%40FOHKJIFAJEHAJ%3FL%40HBFBHFJJNVBLBH%40DLt%40Db%40B%5CBRDV%3F%40DT%40BDLT%60%40HFFDFDLFLDLDJBL%40J%40J%3FXAx%40Gz%40Cp%40Ej%40%3F%5C%3FR%40D%3FPGLBLBXFF%40FDLFNLLN%40%40kshxFxbibMJBB%40%40%40%40%40%40BBFBJJ%60%40FTHXLXJPHJHJRLLDPFNBRBJ%40P%40N%3FPARCREPELGNITMNMJK%5Ce%40%5Ci%40cehxF%7CdibM%7C%40%3Fh%40%40PBT%40L%40J%40TDf%40HND%5CHRFPFVJXNHDXVZXtCxCb%40d%40XVXRRNPJRHb%40RXJTHb%40PVLTNVNNNh%40d%40RRafgxFrwibMn%40%60At%40jAHLLNPN%5E%5CRLTP%5ENl%40RbATD%40JB%5EHD%40rCj%40xDp%40onfxFvdjbMRFf%40cBPk%40alfxFn%60jbMIk%40ESESGOEMMMSSeAs%40WYIcAYqCKeACW%3FK%3FIyrfxFboibMJm%40KAI%40SBWBWHc%40VMHKHMNORGHKRS%60%40

Comment: are you sure you're not passing the 256char limit for a get request?

Comment: I am not sure. I still get a map back, it just is zoomed out to show continents with a polyline that cuts through NA and Oceans.